# How to make li clickable without affecting inner anchor?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of products for which I am using below li:

When user clicks anywhere on the li I want use to send to product details page e.g. /product/id/. When user mouse over the li I also display an icon which when clicked allows users to add product in Favorites.

```
<ul>
        <li class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
                <a href="/product/123/">
                    <thumb>
                        <div class="thumb">
                            <img src="/images/company-logo.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </thumb>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <div class="item-actions autohide pull-right">
                    <a title="Add to Favorites"><i class="material-icons">favorite</i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="media-heading b">
                    <a href="/product/123">Demo Product</a>
                </div>
                <div class="text-sm">
                    <div style="height:16px;overflow:hidden;">Demo Manufacturer</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I know I can make the whole li clickable and send user to product details page using javascript.

```
<li (click)="sendToproductDetailsPage(123)">
.....
</li>
```

But the issue with this approach is that when I click on Favorite icon, it also send users to product details page.

Can anyone please guide how to achieve this with pure JavaScript?

Comment: The spec prohibits interactive elements to have interactive decedents. Your best option is to create a structure like this: `li > a.product + a.favorite` and manipulate the appearance with CSS where you could have the product link occupy all space and the favorite link be `absolutely` positioned

Comment: Is `<a title="Add to Favorites"><i class="material-icons">favorite</i></a>` "Favorite icon"? where `click` should not "send to product details page"?

Comment: @Aziz: There is no spec violation above. The spec doesn't say you can't have click handlers on elements containing elements that can be clicked; half the web would be broken. "Interactive content" has [a specific meaning](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) in the spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You clearly have an event handler for the "Favorite" `a` link that handles adding the thing to the favorites. Have that event handler stop propagation. Since the click stops as of that `a`, it never bubbles up to the `li`, and you don't have to worry about it triggering the `li`'s click handler.

If you're hooking up events through `addEventListener`, your handler gets an event object that has `stopPropgation`, so:

```
yourEventArgument.stopPropagation();
```

If you're using `onxyz`-style event handlers, `return false` from the handler; it does the same thing `stopPropgation` does (more on my blog: [*The true story on `return false`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html)).

Comment: Thank you so much T.J. Crowder event.stopPropagation() was what I needed.